# Organizing hyperlinks into columns

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Be warned I am a newbie so this may be a simple question to you. Anyway I have 6 hyperlinks that I'd like to position into two vertical columns of three. You don't have to write the entire code out just point me in the right direction for the most effective route to completing this , thanks! Picture provided [image]

Comment: Please post your existing HTML and CSS to http://jsbin.com, edit your comment to share the link and post a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 2 unordered list inside a container, and use `float` to place it side by side, alternatively you can also use `display: inline-block;` but better stick with floats, like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDuM4/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap ul {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther is improvment of Mr.Alien code:

```
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap ul {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.wrap ul:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```